# How do I send an empty dateTime with NUSOAP?

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I'm using NUSOAP on the server-side of a web service. I want to return a null `dateTime` element, but I'm not sure how.

If I return the values `false` or `''` , the result is

```
<due_date xsi:type="xsd:dateTime" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

whereas I would like it to be

```
<due_date xsi:type="xsd:dateTime" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:null="true"/>
```

If I return `null`, the `due_date` tag is not present anymore, which causes problems on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `null` or `''`, explicitly return `new soapval( 'element','xsd:dateTime', null )`.

(Some) courtesy of the [NuSOAP Sourceforge forums](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/forums/forum/193579/topic/2232146).